# Display Mangers didn't load after login screen in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, login, 18.04, display-manager

I tried to install **Xfce** Desktop environment in **Ubuntu 18.04 (gdm3 set as default)**. After installation rebooted the system, then on the login time select the Xfce as the display manager, but didn't load the display manager.
  Uninstalled Xfce packages then i tried different option in the list

1. Gnome Classic
2. Gnome
3. Ubuntu
4. Ubuntu Wayland
5. KDE

Able to start display manager by command startx from the console.
In GUI login it nothing load..

Answer (score 1):

You have many display managers ..., - then you need to choose, which display manager you actually want and make this display manager active
with command as follows... don't forget to install xdm package :

First you have to disable the current running display-manager of gnome:

> sudo systemctl stop gdm.service

Then ..., when xdm is installed, do this:

> sudo systemctl start xdm.service
>
> reboot